# JTAppleCalendar how to hide the header from displaying for the current section

Tags: jtapplecalendar

I am building a calendar using `JTAppleCalendar`. I have vertical scrolling enabled, supplementary headers showing each month's name and the scrolling mode to stopAtEachSection. With this setup, after scrolling, it always stops at the start of the section header, thereby displaying the header too for the currentSection.  However, I want to show the headers only while scrolling and after scrolling stops, just show the visible dates for the currentSection.(similar to the iPhone Calendar app's month view mode)
How do I accomplish this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two JTAppleCalendar delegate:

`calendarDidScroll(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView)` and `scrollDidEndDecelerating(for calendar: JTAppleCalendarView)`

and call animation View within those two with opposite alpha value to each other, something as follow:

```
//initial alpha value of the view

 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            //adjust alpha value of the view 
        }
```